# Problem with array index and element repetition

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, oop, indexing

Hello everyone I have a question!
I have an array in which there is another array and 4 buttons and there is a button that adds +1 element to the array, the problem is that when adding a new element to the array, the new element copies the state of the previous element

Tried to compare index of inner array with total array

Comment: Please the code that you have tried and doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.